# Adding the year to dates in date column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, data-cleaning

I am doing some data cleaning and I have a csv with a date column containing “month day”, for example: April 12. I want to add the year 2020 to each date in that column, so that I have: April 12 2020.

[image: here is a quick screenshot of the df]

I’ve tried using pandas and datetime, but I feel like I am clearly missing an easy answer.

Thanks!

edit:

I should have said this before, I have already imported the csv and I want to add the year after the fact. Furthermore, I have already told pandas that the ‘onset’ column contains dates.

edit 2:

Thanks to: You can try  df['onset'] = df['onset'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2020)) in that case – MrNobody33 13

That worked! Thanks for all the help,I’ll try to make my future posts more clear in the future and add my data when asking a question. I knew there had to be a simple answer!

Comment: instead of an image please paste a snippet of your data

Comment: Are you trying to edit the csv file itself, or do you want to import the data and *then* add the year information?

Comment: @0p3r4t0r I am importing the data, then adding the year information.

Comment: @KuldeepSinghSidhu I am on an iPad and it won’t let me use snippets

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
df['onset'] = df['onset'].astype(str) +'2020'
```

Comment: thanks, but since I’ve already parsed the dates I’m getting 1900-04-222020. Is there a way to do it using datetime?

Comment: can you show your data frame? I can only see date and month in your data frame

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to edit the csv itself, you can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'test.csv'                               #path of the .csv
df = pd.read_csv(path)                          #reads the file
df['onset'] = df['onset'].astype(str) +' 2020'  #Add the year
df.to_csv("test.csv", index=False)              #modify the file
```

Or, if you want to edit the dataframe imported from that csv, you can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
path = 'test.csv' 
path = 'pathofthecsv'
df = pd.read_csv(path)                          #reads the file
df['onset'] = df['onset'].astype(str) +' 2020'  #Add the year
```

Comment: Since I’ve already parsed the dates in pandas I am getting: 1900-04-222020

Comment: You can try   `df['onset'] = df['onset'].apply(lambda dt: dt.replace(year=2020))` in that case